# Android Simulator how does it connect to local IP addresses?

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to implement an Android application in Windows 7 using Eclipse. I am trying to connect the Android simulator to the local test server in my company, but for some reason, it cannot connect to the test server.

If there is any settings or configurations for this, please let me know.

I have tried to do the same from a MAC machine using iPhone emulator and I am facing the same problem. How would this emulator connect to the local servers in my company as currently it all goes to live servers? What configurations are required to be done on the simulators, and how?

If I try to connect to the test server from normal Windows machine browser, I am able to successfully connect to it through the web browser; but when I try to do the same from the Android emulator browser, it cannot connect to it.

The emulator points to the live network and not the local network in my company. This is strange and I know that I need to do some settings for it, but I am not sure where these settings are done and how.

Answer (score 0):

If accessing local computer:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyLocalServer.html // URL to use in computer browser
http://10.0.2.2:8080/MyLocalServere.html  // URL to use in emulator browser
```

Also try using a local IP to connect to any local servers. Do not use host names.

**Dont:**

```
http://mylocalserver.org/
```

**Do:**

```
http://192.168.1.125:portnumber
```

You have to set up IP-based hosts instead of name-based.

Answer (score 0):

Emulator its - VM. This use virtual network connection. I think you need before chech this connection (this connection may bee stay as NAT, Breedge, Native IP adress, Proxy).
Since you do not work  iPhone emulator, most likely you, IP adress virtual network connectionб which uses Emulator, does not match the address area of the local network, and routing occurs

Answer (score -1):

This may help you...

Taken from the android docs:

> If you need to refer to your host computer's localhost, such as when you want the emulator client to contact a server running on the same host, use the alias 10.0.2.2 to refer to the host computer's loopback interface. From the emulator's perspective, localhost (127.0.0.1) refers to its own loopback interface.

http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias

Comment: an explanation would be nice along with the down vote. what i am pointing out is that the emulator does not get an ip address that is on the same network as your local machine. to communicate with the localhost (your machine) or other endpoints on the companies network, you need to go via the underlying linux architectures localhost loop back interface, 10.0.2.2. This is at least part of the problem and may help with find a solution to other part..